# Hibernate Exception Missing table postgresql

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I have switched an Spring application from mariaDB to Postgres and I'm having trouble with hibernate to recognize the tables.

I'm using Postgres 9.5.3

I have no trouble to connect to the database via Intelj with the same connection data, and I can also query the database via Intelij persistence hql console so the mapping of the entities looks ok, but when I run the app I get the following error (the table mentioned in the error is actually the first entity that gets scaned during deploy):

```
2016-06-08 12:01:16.464 [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/scgl/config/JpaConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: agregated_bet_results
2016-06-08 12:01:16.545 [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/scgl/config/JpaConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: agregated_bet_results
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4809) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1761017124.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_45]
08-Jun-2016 12:01:16.548 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: agregated_bet_results
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1335) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:525) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
08-Jun-2016 12:01:16.549 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

my hibernate conf:

```
dataSource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/socergladiator
dataSource.username=postgres
dataSource.password=admin

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
```

The pom.xml dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
     <version>9.4.1208</version>
</dependency>
```

The Jpa spring config class:

```
package com.scgl.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.scgl.Application;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Application.class)
class JpaConfig {

        @Value("${dataSource.driverClassName}")
        private String driver;
        @Value("${dataSource.url}")
        private String url;
        @Value("${dataSource.username}")
        private String username;
        @Value("${dataSource.password}")
        private String password;
        @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
        private String dialect;
        @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
        private String hbm2ddlAuto;

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            config.setDriverClassName(driver);
            config.setJdbcUrl(url);
            config.setUsername(username);
            config.setPassword(password);
            config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
            config.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true");

            return new HikariDataSource(config);
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);

            String entities = ClassUtils.getPackageName(Application.class);
            String converters = ClassUtils.getPackageName(Jsr310JpaConverters.class);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(entities, converters);

            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

            Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
            jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, dialect);
            jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddlAuto);
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
        }
    }
```

The database design:
[image]

Comment: try disabling the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto. Use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none` and see what happens.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for editing `postgre` to `postgres`. That's one of my pet peeves.

Comment: Your problem can be related with setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate` in your Hibernate config and have your entity mapped to a view. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019995/hibernate-mysql-views-and-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah it was a stupid error, I have the schema = "socergladiator" definition in @Table, in mysql this worked, postgres handels this differently, I just removed the  schema = "socergladiator" from @Table annotation and it started to work.

btw I have no problems using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate, it was probbably a problem in older postgres versions